# Can you install and play GemCraft Labyrinth on multiple machines?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

I bought the premium edition of *GemCraft Labyrinth* 2 months ago. I registered the game and played it on my PC [using this link](http://armorgames.com/play/10317/gemcraft-labyrinth).

I want to play it on my laptop. I disconnect from my account on my PC and tried to connect to my account on my laptop, and I get the following message:

> Sorry but the Armor Games Services are temporary unavailable. Please
>   try again again soon.

I'm able to reconnect to my account on my PC but still unable when using my laptop.